# A simple client/server authentication protocol

Tags: authentication, protocol-analysis

Some days ago I asked for a help to find and correct the problems of an authentication protocol. I closed the post because I was convinced I can correct it but, unfortunately I'm having some troubles. The "old" post is the following:
I'm dealing with this problem: establish if the following protocol is 'secure' and, if it isn't, modify it to make it secure.

I will use the subsequent notation to describe the protocol:

- $N$ is a nonce
- $X \longrightarrow Y: \space   M$
  to indicate that $X$ sends $M$ to $Y$
- $K_{XY}$ to indicate the symmetric key shared by $X$ and $Y$
- and $K_{XY}(M)$  to indicate that the message $M$ has been encrypted with the symmetric key $K_{XY}$.

The protocol allows a client $C$ to authenticate itself to a server $S$ using an authentication service $A$.

$C \longrightarrow S:\space  C$ 
$S \longrightarrow C:\space   N$ 
$C \longrightarrow S:\space   K_{CA}(N)$
$S \longrightarrow A:\space   K_{SA}(C, K_{CA}(N))$
$A \longrightarrow S:\space   K_{SA}(N)$

$S$ authenticates $C$ if and only if the nonce received $N$, got by the authentication service ($A$), is equal to the nonce sent to $C$.

Assuming the communication channel is not secure, an attacker (called Eve) can impersonate $C$ simply sending the message "C" and $K_{CA}(N)$ whenever $C$ tries to authenticate himself.

How to avoid impersonation and offline nonce-guessing in this case? Any suggestion? I don't want the answer to the problem, just a few tips to continue on my own. At the end, I want to say that I know how to make the protocol secure but my answer consists in completely change the protocol described above, and so I think my answer is not the most appropriate.
 Recently I thought to modify the protocol as follows:
$C \longrightarrow S:\space  C$ 
$S \longrightarrow C:\space   K_{SA}(N)$ 
$C \longrightarrow S:\space   K_{CA}(K_{SA}(N))$
$S \longrightarrow A:\space   K_{SA}(C, K_{CA}(K_{SA}(N)))$
$A \longrightarrow S:\space   K_{SA}(N)$
 Can it work now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Eve knows $C, \space N, \space K_{CA}(N)$ then she is able to impersonate $C$ just by following the protocol you described above.

If she just knows $K_{CA}(N)$ for a single $N$ then the effectiveness of the attack depends on the set wherein $N$ is picked.

But **as you are supposing that the communication channel is not secure**, an attacker could spy several authentication session to get a sufficient number of pairs $(N, K_{CA}(N))$ to successfully attack with high probability.

Comment: Alright! Thanks @Raoul722!
But how can Eve impersonate *C* precisely? She can send the message "C", (because it is known) and then what?? Can she ask to *C* to encrypt the nonce *N* for her? I'm not convinced of this..

p.s. forgive my English

Comment: @Process0 No, you said you admit that Eve knows $K_{CA}(N)$. So Eve sends $C$ then receives $N$ and then send back $K_{CA}(N)$. She **exactly** follows the protocol you gave.

Comment: Alright! My problem/answer is: does C respond with the nonce encrypted if he didn't request any authentication to the server? If yes, obviously is sufficient what you said. What if he doesn't?

Comment: @Process0 I don't understand your question. How is it related to the scenario in which Eve tries to impersonate $C$? Anyway, it seems a good practice to not send $K_{CA}(N)$ if authentication wasn't requested. But in the case I described above, Eve could spy the authentication protocol **when $C$ initiates it** (so he would send the encrypted nonce).

Comment: @Process0 The problem here is that the signature of the challenge **only** depends of the nonce $N$. So as soon as the same $N$ is used it is easy to impersonate $C$. To make this protocol more robust, we could introduce another contextual parameter $x$ in $K_{CA}(N,x)$ which does not appear as plaintext, known by $S$ and which would be different in an other session (date and hour for example ?).

Comment: Hi @Raoul722, and thanks again! But now I'm not sure you're right. As before, Eve (that doesn't know the timestamp *T* (for example) sent by *C*) can forward the initial message ("C") and K<sub>CA</sub>(*N*, *T*) to *S* to authenticate herself whenever *C* tries. So I don't know..

Comment: @Process0 Well I was supposing that Eve can only know $K_{CA}(N)$ by spying previous authentications and so getting $N$, $K_{CA}(N)$. What are your assumptions to consider that Eve knows $K_{CA}(N,T)$?

Comment: As you said some days ago, Eve can spy the protocol when *C* initiates it. Now, with *T*, why it not the same? Eve can wait that *C* sends the first message (and afterwards the message+timestamp encrypted) and when he sends the encrypted one, Eve can send the two messages to *S*. Is this correct?

Comment: I've just modified the post. Can you please tell me if now it works?

Comment: @Process0 No, it does not solve your problem. Eve will just get $(K_{SA}(N), K_{CA}(K_{SA}(N)))$ couples instead of $(N, K_{CA}(N))$ couples but the problem is unchanged. The timestamp version solves the problem when Eve tries to impersonate $C$ and when **she** initiates the protocol.

Comment: Why she cannot do the same with a timestamp?? I don't understand this thing. Explain it a little more in detail, please. Why she can't get the couple (*N*, K_{CA}(*N, T*))  as she get the couple (*N*, K_{CA}(*N*))??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38636/discussion-between-raoul722-and-process0).